# Spring form:errors doesn't render

Tags: java, validation, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-form

I have fiollowing controller method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/addNewAdmin")
    public String adminUsers(@ModelAttribute @Valid TerminalAdmin newAdmin, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap model, Principal principal, HttpSession session) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            ...
            model.addAttribute("newAdmin",newAdmin);            
            return "admin/adminUsers";          
        }
        ....
    }
```

and following model:

```
Entity
@Table(name = "terminal_admin")
public class TerminalAdmin {

    .....

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    @Size(max = 255)
    @NotEmpty
    private String email;

}
```

jsp:

```
    <form:form modelAttribute="newAdmin" action="/admin/addNewAdmin">
            <div class="line">
                <label for="">email</label>
                <form:input path="email" type="text" name="emal" value=""/>
                !!!<form:errors path="email" cssClass="error"/>!!!
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
    </form:form>
```

I input empty email into form

In debug in controller method I see that `bindingResult` has errors that email shouldn't be empty.

jsp renders as:

```
<form id="newAdmin" action="/admin/addNewAdmin" method="post">
            <div class="line">
                <label for="">email</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="">
                !!!!!!
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working after replace

```
newAdmin
```

with

```
terminalAdmin
```

thx second point of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2912049/2674303